# Multiple row insertion Azure Mobile Services Offline, sync with the backend

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to modify Table Controllers in Azure Mobile Services .Net backend to handle multi-insertion per http request?
After coming back online it takes 2+ minutes for my app to sync its data. over 70% of the 2 minute is wasted over the network handshaking overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar. My app creates around 10,000 new rows every time a user creates a new project so I made a custom controller in my Mobile Service to accept this. After the 10,000 entities are inserted I pull all of them back down to the local sync database.

I first created a custom controller.

```
public class BatchInsertController : ApiController
{
    DbContext context;

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        this.context = new DbContext();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> BatchInsert(List<Entity> entities)
    {
        try
        {
            this.context.Entities.AddRange(entities);
            await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Then I would call this custom controller method from my client code.

```
var entities = new List<Entity>();
// Add a bunch of entities to the list...

foreach (List<Entity> chunkedEntities in entities.ChunksOf(1000))
{
    var response = await _client.InvokeApiAsync<List<Entity>, bool>("batchinsert", chunkedEntities);
}
```

I would have over 10,000 records at a time so I created an extension method to chunk the list and send 1,000 records at a time.

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> ChunksOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int size)
{
    List<T> chunk = new List<T>(size);
    foreach (T element in sequence)
    {
        chunk.Add(element);
        if (chunk.Count == size)
        {
            yield return chunk;
            chunk = new List<T>(size);
        }
    }
    if (chunk.Any())
    {
        yield return chunk;
    }
}
```

After that I just did a PullAsync() on my local db. I came up with this after reading through [this article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543789/How-to-parse-chunk-by-chunk-a-large-CSV-file-and-b)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I have a little more complicated situation that I have to insert the data into localdb. Users can do offline data manipulation and when it's back online I need to take out all the dirty rows from buffer and push them in bulk to the server in order (keeping the foreign key requirements). Implementing this part is as costly as implementing the offline sync altogether. I was thinking maybe there's a way through some configurations to have azure sdk do this for me.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying now. Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this via configuration yet.